# Using the `validate` package inside an Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-s4

I wish to include same validations inside my Rmarkdown report. Here is a minimal example:

````
---
title: "My Report"
output:
  html_document:
    mode: selfcontained
    theme: null
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(validate)
rules <- validator(
    "Species" %in% names(.),
    is.character(Species),
    !is.na(Species)
)
chk <- confront(dat=iris, x=rules)
summary(chk)
```
````

I would expect a `data.frame` as the result, but I get (when I call `rmarkdown::render` on a file with the content above):

```
##     Length      Class       Mode 
##          3 validation         S4
```

It seems that the S4 summary method is not called correctly. I tried to call `validate::summary.validations` but that did not help.

Any ideas how to call `summary` from inside an rmarkdown document?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem - I render the markdown and it prints a three row data frame with the results. Calling the function directly could work, but `summary.validations()` isn't exported from the namespace, so you'd have to use `validate:::summary.validations()`.  When I tried that, I got `NULL` as the output.  However, when I used `validate::summary(chk)`, I got the intended answer.  Perhaps try that? (R v4.3.2, validate v1.1.3, rmarkdown v2.25, macOS 13.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `summary.validations()` function isn't exported from the namespace, so you'd have to use `validate:::summary.validations(chk)`, but when I tried that, I got `NULL` as the output. However, when I used `validate::summary(chk)`, I got the intended answer. (R v4.3.2, validate v1.1.3, rmarkdown v2.25, macOS 13.6)